# Google sheets python script conditional formatting custom formula

Tags: python, google-sheets, formatting

I want to use a script to format the background color for cells in two separate ranges based on values in a single range.

Ranges to be formatted:
AU6:BL405
BN6:CE405

Based on value = 1 in range:
A6:R405

I'm hoping that using a script will make the file more efficient compared to setting up the conditional formatting using the custom formula formatting function in Sheets.

I would appreciate any help!

Here is the code I've come up with so far:

```
SpreadsheetID: xxx

myRangeA = {
    startRowIndex: 6,
    startColumnIndex: 47,
    endColumnIndex: 64,

}

myRangeB = {
    startRowIndex: 6,
    startColumnIndex: 66,
    endColumnIndex: 83,

}

reqs = [
    {addConditionalFormatRule: {
        index: 0,
        rule: {
            ranges: [ myRangeA, myRange B ],
            booleanRule: {
                format: {
                  backgroundColor: {backgroundColor: {red: 0.8}}}
                condition: {
                    type: CUSTOM_FORMULA,
                    values:
                        [{userEnteredValue: =A6=1}]
                },
            },
        },
    }},
]

SHEETS.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SHEET_ID,
        body={requests: reqs}).execute()
```

Comment: Please, provide more information about your script and an issue that you have with it. Now it's not possible to write something useful related to your problem

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've added some code that might be useful for the task.

Comment: Can you provide the error message and the issue of your script? And is your script a python script? Can you add a tag related to language you are using? Such information will help users think of your solution.